# How can I sort the results of a LINQ query

Tags: c#

I have the following query. Is there an easy way that I could sort the results in numeric order 
of RowKey. Currently RowKey is a string. I would like to sort _rowData and NOT modify this query as I want to try some different sort orders and I'm looking for one line changes and not to redo the query.

```
var _rowData = (from qu in _que.GetAll(
  u => u.PartitionKey == partitionKey )
  select new {
    qu.PartitionKey,
    qu.RowKey,
    qu.Style,
    qu.ShortTitle,
    ModifiedToString = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}", qu.Modified)
});
```

I want to do the sorting outside of the LINQ query. The reason is that actually I want to be able to let the user choose a sort of RowKey, ModifiedToString and ShortTitle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the OrderBy extension, you don't modify the original query, it just enumerates the same values:

```
var _rowData = ...
var _rowDataSortedByRowKey = _rowData.OrderBy( u => u.RowKey );
var _rowDataSortedByModifiedToString = _rowData.OrderBy( u => u.ModifiedToString );
var _rowDataSortedByShortTitle = _rowData.OrderBy( u => u.ShortTitle );
var _rowDataSortedByOther = _rowData.OrderBy( ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order the elements of a LINQ query using the [orderby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756) keyword:

> **OrderBy - Simple 2**
>
> This sample uses orderby to sort a list of words by length.
>
> ```
> public void Linq29()
> {
>     string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry" };
>
>     var sortedWords =
>         from w in words
>         orderby w.Length
>         select w;
>
>     Console.WriteLine("The sorted list of words (by length):");
>     foreach (var w in sortedWords)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(w);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The sorted list of words (by length):
>
> ```
> apple
> cherry
> ```

You can also use the [Enumerable.OrderBy Extension Method](http://Enumerable.OrderBy%3CTSource,%20TKey%3E%20Method):

```
var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(w => w.Length);
```

If you want to order by different criteria, you can pass a different key selector for each criterion:

```
if (c == "Length")
    sortedWords = words.OrderBy(w => w.Length);
else
    sortedWords = words.OrderBy(w => w);
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to do this outside of the LINQ query. The reason is that actually I want to be able to let the user choose a sort of RowKey, ModifiedToString and ShortTitle. I was thinking this could be three different resort options after the above query.

Comment: @Robert Dawson: Then make a second query using the first query as input? `var query = from x _rowData orderby x.RowKey select x;`

Comment: thanks dtb. I think this is the solution i wanted. Just one question. How do I change the string so I can sort numerically. Currently row 9 comes after row 80.

Comment: @Robert Dawson: Parse the string to an integer using [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx): `var query = from x _rowData orderby int.Parse(x.RowKey) select x;`

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
_rowData.Sort((a, b) => Convert.ToInt32(a.Key).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(b.Key)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the DataRowComparer.Default in the Distinct statement.

Example:

```
var query = (from c in functiongettable().AsEnumerable()
            orderby c.Field<string>("Name")
            select c).Distinc(DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Comment: DataRowComparer? Sorry but what is that? I am using RowKey which is a string representation of a numeric rowid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderByDescending()

Something like:

```
(from qu in _que.OrderByDescending(u => u.RowKey).GetAll(
  u => u.PartitionKey == partitionKey )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OrderBy extension method in the System.Linq namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264.aspx

This method will allow you to add ordering to your query conditionally.

```
var _rowData = (from qu in _que.GetAll(
  u => u.PartitionKey == partitionKey )
  select new {
    qu.PartitionKey,
    qu.RowKey,
    qu.Style,
    qu.ShortTitle,
    ModifiedToString = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}", qu.Modified)
});

// Let's say the user has selected they want to sort by RowKey
// and ModifiedToString, but not ShortTitle.
bool sortByRowKey = true; 
bool sortByModifiedToString = true;
bool sortByShortTitle = false;

var query = _rowData.AsQueryable();

if(sortByRowKey) {
    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.RowKey);
}

if(sortByModifiedToString) {
    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.ModifiedToString);
}

if(sortByShortTitle) {
    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.ShortTitle);
}

// Now let's call ToList() to execute the query and get the ordered data.
var _orderedData = query.ToList();
```